# Can I bind solutions to TFS source control after I have checked-in the solution files?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, directory, projects-and-solutions

For a new project I have created a local folder tree with empty Visual Studio solutions and projects. At this moment the solutions are not attached to source control.

Now I want to add entire folder structure with all the solutions to the TFS.

Do I need to bind all the solutions to source control before I check-in them? 
Or I can just check-in all the folders and files as they are now, and then later I can use Visual Studio to bind the solutions to the TFS source control?

I am afraid that if I try to bind solutions, I'll be asked for a path on the TFS, but as I haven't my folder structure checked in yet, I won't have the folders on the TFS where to attach my solutions.

Comment: I use VS 2010 and TFS 2010 and often times when I go to open a solution that is checked into source control but is not bound, it asks me if I want to bind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to bind them before you can check them in. Binding basically means TFS server details are embedded into the solution file and project file of the project.

So, essentially you CANNOT perform any source control related operation without binding.

You should perform the following steps:

```
1. Bind the solution
2. Create your folder structure
3. Checkin
```

Do you see any problem with that ?

Comment: Won't Visual Studio ask me for a full path on a TFS when I bind the solution? At that moment there will be no actual folders on TFS yet, so I won't be able to set the correct path.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. When you checkin, the folder structure will be automatically created in TFS to mirror your source folder structure.

Comment: Oh, now I see - TFS creates all the folders for me at the moment I bind the solution. I guess, I am too used to SVN (you have to create everything manually in SVN because you cannot commit anything into non-existing subfolders).

Comment: I believe its at checkin time, not bind time

Comment: Madhur my problem is, when i bind the solution it works fine. But when i restart my system i am not able to open the solution from TFS and also i am not able to checkin-checkout directory.

Answer (score 3):

You can check a bunch of files into TFS through the source control explorer and then later open the solution and bind the files to source control.  You go through File | Source Control | Change Source Control and click all the checkboxes.    TFS will create, add, update files as needed and then you can commit all of the pending checkins.